# Insert data with mysqli not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert data into mysql with mysqli.  My connection details are correct, but it will not insert.  I've tried with and without backticks.

```
if ($query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `items` (`user_id`, `name`, `due_date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
$query->bind_param('iss', $_SESSION['id'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['dueDate']);
$query->execute(); 


}
```

Comment: That looks good. Are you sure that `$_SESSION['id']`, `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['dueDate']` are all set? It may pay to validate those before binding them.

Comment: I am positive they are all set.

Comment: Can you add more checks?  See if the bind fails: `if (!$query->bind_param('iss', $_SESSION['id'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['dueDate'])) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $query->errno . ") " . $query->error;
}` ... and the same can be done with execute: `if (!$query->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $query->errno . ") " . $query->error;
}` ... you can also add an `else` block to your prepare check as well. Output something like `did not prepare`, or whatever.

Comment: display the error message? [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments)